# Probability question involving throwing a die until we get a certain result

Tags: probability, problem-solving

> You roll a dice until you get the number $1$ four times. What is the probability that you get exactly $10$ numbers under the value of four?

My attempt: First, I tried to calculate only the event that there are $10$ rolls. So, we want to choose two numbers $(2,3)$ to appear $6$ times, and of course the number $1$ four times. The probability to get those numbers: $(\frac{2}{6})^6(\frac{1}{6})^4$ . On top of that, we would like to arrange them, so we get $\binom {9}{3}$ to arrange the number $1$ (I chose $\binom {9}{3}$ here because we know there is $1$ at the end). For numbers $2$ and $3$, we have $\binom {2}{1}$ possibilities for choosing one of the numbers, and $$\binom {6}{6}\binom{0}{0} + \binom {6}{5}\binom{1}{1} + \binom {6}{4}\binom{2}{2} + \binom {6}{3}\binom{3}{3} + \binom {6}{2}\binom{4}{4} + \binom {6}{1}\binom{5}{5} + \binom {6}{0}\binom{6}{6}$$ ways to arrange them. So, the probability for that event is :

$$(\frac {2}{6})^6(\frac {1}{6})^4\binom {9}{3}\binom {2}{1} \left[\binom {6}{6}\binom{0}{0} + \binom {6}{5}\binom{1}{1} + \binom {6}{4}\binom{2}{2} + \binom {6}{3}\binom{3}{3} + \binom {6}{2}\binom{4}{4} + \binom {6}{1}\binom{5}{5} + \binom {6}{0}\binom{6}{6}\right] \approx 0.01138$$

That is, as mentioned above, only one event of the probability question. There is an infinite sum of events, where in those events we get a number that is bigger or equal to four. So, we have $\frac 3 6$ possibilities for choosing one of those numbers. The probability of this event is $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac {1}{2})^n = \frac {1}{\frac {1}{2}} = 2 $$

So I multiplied the result above with $2$, and my final answer is $\approx 0.02276$.

I'm not certain with my final answer. In fact, I'm pretty sure I'm mistaken. I think my logic here is not right. Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: Note that we can ignore any toss $≥4$, those simply do not matter.  Thus we effectively have a fair three sided die with faces $1,2,3$.  Now you are just asking for the probability that we see the fourth $1$ on the $14^{th}$ toss (again, ignoring all the irrelevant tosses).

Comment: @lulu Don't you want to see the fourth $1$ on the *tenth* relevant toss?

Comment: @Henry  Oh, yes.  You are right.  I (incorrectly) read the thing as asking for exactly $10$ non-$1$ tosses less than $4$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for answering. A couple of questions.  How come can we ignore all the toss which is bigger or equal to four? Also, don't we need to calculate the probability that we roll three times the number one, and for the rest of the rolls we get only 2 or 3?

Comment: Because those higher rolls have no impact on the count.  In the end, you only care about the "relevant" throws...i.e., those less than $4$.

Comment: @lulu I see. So, if I got it right, then $(\frac {3}{6})^9\frac {1}{6}$ is the right answer?

Comment: I believe the answer is a little more complicated than the above.

Comment: @Yoxbox There are a couple things you are missing. As we are ignoring the faces $\geq 4$, for all intended purposes the probability we roll a $1$ is $\frac{1}{3}$ (and likewise for $2$ and $3$). Also, we need to account for the fact that there must be exactly $3$ ones in the first $9$ rolls.

Comment: @Yoxbox: Your expression seems still to take account of the fact that the die has six sides.  As the others have indicated, you can ignore sides $4$, $5$, and $6$.  You are dealing with a three-sided die (as it were).  How many sequences of length $10$ are there from the alphabet $\{1, 2, 3\}$?  How many of them satisfy the condition?  Therein lies your answer.

Comment: @Alan Abraham I see it now. For some reason my head stopped thinking clearly yesterday. Thanks for the help ( to everyone) ! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize the discussion in the comments:

The only relevant tosses are $\{1,2,3\}$.  Getting anything higher than $3$ just wastes a turn.  If, say, the toss sequence was $\{6,1,2,5,1,4,3,6,1,1\}$  we would only be concerned with the subsequence $\{1,2,1,3,1,1\}$, simply ignoring the higher tosses.

Thus the problem is equivalent to the following:  Given a fair three sided die, what is the probability that the fourth $1$ is observed on the tenth toss?

Since each of the faces on our (virtual) three sided die are equally probable, this is simply $$\frac 13\times \binom {9}3\times  \left(\frac 13\right)^3\times \left(\frac 23\right)^6\approx .09104$$

Sanity check:  considering the six sided die, we expect it to to take six tosses to see a $1$, hence $24$ tosses to see four $1's$.  Of the $20$ non-$1's$ in that expected sequence we expect $\frac 25$ of them to be either $2$ or $3$, hence $8$.  A straight forward computation shows that the above calculation does indeed yield $8$ for this expectation.

Note:  of course you can do the calculation using the six sided die but in that case you need to consider all possible sequence lengths (well, all those of length $≥10$ at least).  Nothing theoretically wrong with that, but it forces you to compute a rather messy summation.  To be sure, that infinite sum converges quite quickly so you only need to consider the first thirty terms or so.  Worth doing if no other reason than to confirm the result.

Comment: In the sanity check part, coukd you elaborate what straight forward computation are you doing?

Comment: @Yoxbox  To generalize the formula, note that the probability that there are exactly $k$ relevant tosses is $p_k=\frac 13\times \frac {k-1}3\times \left(\frac 13\right)^3\times \left(\frac 23\right)^{k-4}$.  Then the desired expectation is $\sum_{i=4}^{\infty}kp_k$ which can be done in closed form or, more easily, numerically.

Comment: Typos in the last comment:    $\frac {k-1}3$ should have been $\binom {k-1}3$ and the summation index should be $k$, not $i$.  [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bk*%281%2F3%29*BinomialCoefficient%5Bk-1%2C3%5D*%281%2F3%29%5E3*%282%2F3%29%5E%28k-4%29%2C%7Bk%2C4%2Cinfinity%7D%5D) is Wolfram alphas computation.  Note that this is $12$, not $8$, because it includes the four $1's$.  If you replace the multiplicative factor $k$ by $k-4$, you get $8$.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is a little more involved.

Let $L$ be the index when the $4$th one appears. Then the probability in question is (note the denominator is $5$. not $6$!)
$\sum_{k=10}^\infty P[L=k] \binom{k-4}{6}({2 \over 5})^6 ({3 \over 5})^{k-10}$.

To compute $P[L=k]$, note that the $k$th index is **always** $1$, and the other three can appear anywhere else. Hence
$P[L=k] = {1 \over 6} \binom{k-1}{3} ({1 \over 6})^3 ({5 \over 6})^{k-4}$.

Comment: In $P[L=k]$, what is the meaning of $(\frac {5}{6})^{k-4}$ ?

Comment: @Yoxbox The fraction ${5 \over 6}$ to the power of $k-4$?

Comment: Yes, I mean, what does he represent?

Comment: @Yoxbox three $1$s must be selected and $k-4$ 'non' $1$s must be selected, the former have probability ${1 \over 6}$ and the latter ${5 \over 6}$.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I must say, I think your answer describes well the probability in the question , but I dont see a way to find find the sum of the terms.

Comment: It is a bit of work, but mostly a matter of grind and knowing how to sum $\sum_{k=10}^\infty (k-1)(\cdots)(k-9) { 1 \over 2^k}$.